# when entitymanager(session) created in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view article

According to this article, it says that the session is created in the request phase.

> Spring opens a new Hibernate Session at the beginning of the request. These Sessions are not necessarily connected to the database.

But as far as I know, in Spring, when a transaction starts, it gets an entity manager (session). The reason is that there is no need to create an entity manager for logic that does not use JDBC.

```java
@Transactional
@Service
public class DoService {
      // when use this service EntityManager is created;
}
```

I wonder if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: What about database access in a non-transactional method?

Comment: I think non-transactional method is not request EntityManager.

Comment: You missed the point of the _open Session in view_ option: It specifically uses a global `EntityManager` instead of the default behavior, which is as you describe.

Comment: ops.. i missed !! thanks you